# Working with Vertical Grid using DevExpress (ComboBoxEdit Template)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, devexpress, datatemplate

I created VerticalGrid by an example from [How to create a custom GridControl that represents columns horizontally in a way similar to the WinForms VerticalGrid control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/%22%20How%20to%20create%20a%20custom%20GridControl%20that%20represents%20columns%20horizontally%20in%20a%20way%20similar%20to%20the%20WinForms%20VerticalGrid%20control%22)

In my case I have to make one of properties as **ComboBoxEdit**, which bind on Collection from DataContext.
Template as I wrote doesn't work properly.
I try to find any examples for creating **ComboBoxEdit** as **DataTemplate** which would work for this case.

```html
        <DataTemplate x:Key="comboboxCellTemplate" x:Name="comboboxTemplete">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="PART_Editor" 
                              ValueMember="Country" 
                              DisplayMember="Name"
                              IsTextEditable="False"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.CountriesList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>

<view:VerticalGridControl.Rows>
                <view:VerticalRowData RowName="Country" CellTemplate="{StaticResource comboboxCellTemplate}"/>
</view:VerticalGridControl.Rows>
```

Comment: how does your error looks like? no data displayed or anything else? But at first glance one thing i can say is that your itemSource should not refer to the DataContext that way because when beeing in a template your overall dataContext is overriden you should use a syntax like templatedParent or FindAncestor and then refer to the needed datacontext

Comment: @FranckNgako I tried to fix this problem using FindAncestor, but no changes. ItemSource doesn't binding to List.

Comment: ok. well first thing to check, make sure CountriesList has a public visibility and that your are using the correct viewModel, second make sure it contains the values and try to bind it to your view without using a template. if this work then you have to play around with different syntax to access your userControl DataContext.. And third if you don't really  need a template try using ComboxEditSettings